Types missmatch on useMutation and Axios request. TS TanstackQuery Axios
I'm doing login form and need to handle errors from response. So here is code.
export interface ILoginform {
    email: string
    password: string
}

LoginForm.tsx
const { mutate, error, isError, } = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['login'],
    mutationFn(data: ILoginform){
        return authService.main('login', data)
    },
    onSuccess(){
        reset()
        push('/')
    }
})

const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ILoginform> = (data) => {
    mutate(data)
}

return (
 {isError && <label className=" text-xl mb-2 ml-1 text-red-500 capitalize">{
     // @ts-ignore
    error.response.data.message //here is the problem
 }</label>}
)

AuthService.ts
export interface IAuthResponse {
    accessToken: string
    user: IUser
}

export const authService = {
    async main(type: 'login' | 'register', data: ILoginform | IRegform){
    const response = await axiosClassic.post<IAuthResponse>(
        `/auth/${type}`,
        data
    )
    if (response.data.accessToken) saveTokenStorage(response.data.accessToken)
        return response
    },

The problem is that "request" does not exists on type Error. But acctually I can get it, so i used ts-ignore. I khow that's not great and i need to fix types. I've tried put generics to useMutation:
 ... useMutation<ILoginform, AxiosError<{message: string}>> ...
but then there are type errors with mutatationFn
Type '(data: ILoginform) =\> Promise\<AxiosResponse\<IAuthResponse, any\>\>' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction\<ILoginform, void\>'.
and functon mutate
Argument of type 'ILoginform' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.
